# cannot replace a normal view with a late binding view in redshift

Tags: sql, view, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create view in redshift but getting error. Could you please help me how to solve this?

Example:

```
Query : create or replace view medaff_smrtsrc.DMN_STATUS as  SELECT DISTINCT dense_rank()over(order by cs.status,cs.sub_status asc) as  STATUS_SID,CASE WHEN  CS.STATUS  IS NULL     THEN 'Unspecified'   ELSE    TRIM(cs.STATUS) END  as  STATUS,CASE WHEN  CS.SUB_STATUS  IS NULL     THEN 'Unspecified'   ELSE    TRIM(cs.SUB_STATUS) END  as  SUB_STATUS,'sysdate' as  T_INSERT_DT,'ETL' as  T_INSERT_USER From medaff_ref_spectrum.CASE CS WHERE CS.STATUS  IS NOT NULL ;

Error - 0A000: External tables are not supported in views
```

Then I tried with 'with no schema binding'

```
query : create or replace view medaff_smrtsrc.DMN_STATUS as  SELECT DISTINCT dense_rank()over(order by cs.status,cs.sub_status asc) as  STATUS_SID,CASE WHEN  CS.STATUS  IS NULL     THEN 'Unspecified'   ELSE    TRIM(cs.STATUS) END  as  STATUS,CASE WHEN  CS.SUB_STATUS  IS NULL     THEN 'Unspecified'   ELSE    TRIM(cs.SUB_STATUS) END  as  SUB_STATUS,'sysdate' as  T_INSERT_DT,'ETL' as  T_INSERT_USER From medaff_ref_spectrum.CASE CS WHERE CS.STATUS  IS NOT NULL with no schema binding;

Error - 42P16: Cannot replace a normal view with a late binding view
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `DROP` the view and then `CREATE` it again.